# find exacly phrase of sentence, not a path of phrase

Tags: php, find, strpos

I have problem with search tool!
I use `strpos function` to search `$phrase_key` in `$sentence`, and there are some wrong!

```
strpos($sentence , $phrase_key,  0)
$phrase_key = "on the"; 
$sentence1  = "i am sitting on the table"      // Good search
$sentence2  = "the book is on the floor"      // Good search  
$sentence3  = "create function theme to..."   // it not fine
```

- `on the` is a path of `function theme`, and function theme is not phrase i need to find
- Please tell me how to fix this or how to find the wrong search!
  thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Also, what's with these "Good search" and "it not fine"??

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with word boundary `\b` metacharacter:

```
if( preg_match( "~\b$phrase_key\b~", $sentence, $matches ) )
{
    // matched string is now in $matches[0]
}
```

If you are interesting in substring position, use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag:

```
if( preg_match( "~\b$phrase_key\b~", $sentence, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) )
{
    // matched string is now in $matches[0][0]
    // matched string position is now in $matches[0][1]
}
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yY3mH7/1)**</kbd>

---

- Read more about [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- Read more about [PHP Regular Expressions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)